# The logical "then"

Tags: conjunction, logic, mathematics, vocabulary

I am interested in translating the word "then" in logical statements like this: "If a number is prime, then it is squarefree."
Or maybe better: "If *x* is even and *x+y* is odd, then *y* is odd."
In common language one would not use a "then" at all, but in mathematics (including logic) it is very common to emphasize the consequence with a "then".
This logical "then" is not temporal but causal, and I have never seen it in ancient sources at all.
I have not found this sense of "then" in Latin dictionaries.

What would be a good translation of this "then"?
Was there a fixed phrase in the mathematical Latin of, say, 18th and 19th century?
My intuition is to translate "if–then" with *si–deinde*.
I want something that works within a sentence, so that the "then" does not start a stand-alone sentence, but just a consequence clause.

It seems that Gauss does not use a "then" at all in [this example](http://thelatinlibrary.com/gauss.html).
It is possible that the logical "then" was introduced after Latin went out of fashion in mathematics.

Comment: _Si ... deinde_ looks perfectly all right to me. I would certainly use 'then' in conversation, though not on every occasion. Perhaps _igitur_ would suit? Or possibly _ipso facto_? — a [prime number is] ipso facto [squarefree].

Comment: It seems that [Newton](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Philosophiae_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica_-_SECT._I._DE_Methodo_rationum_primarum_%26_ultima_rum.) uses (from time to time) [dein](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddein) and [ergo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dergo). If anyone wants to write the answer, be my guest: I can't do more research for some hours yet.

Comment: Adelard of Bath (1080-1152) has a parenthetical *'necesse est'* ( once with *igitur,*) to indicate certainty. For a confident opinion, he finishes the clause with *'non dubitas.'*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Option 1: *sequitur, ut*

Browsing L&S I came to the entry on the verb [*sequor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsequor), meaning II.B.4, that reads:

> In logical conclusions, *to follow, ensue*; with *subject-clause*,

especially with *ut*. And it cites a pretty clean example from Cicero:

> **Si** hoc enuntiatum: "Veniet in Tusculanum Hortensius" verum non est, **sequitur, ut** falsum sit.” ([Cic. Fat. 28](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0035%3Asection%3D28))

Several other examples from classical times may be found with this construction.

#### Option 2: *ergo*

***Ergo*** seems to me like the most natural choice (one word, no comma needed.)

[L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dergo), lists at least two examples of meanings where *ergo* introduces the consequence in conditional clauses.

- *Consequently, therefore* (...) with **si**, cum, quia, etc.: “ergo ego **nisi** peperissem, Roma non oppugnaretur,” [Liv. 2.40](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0169%3Abook%3D2%3Achapter%3D40).8; "Ergo **quia** sum tangere ausus, haud causificor quin eam ego habeam potissimum." [Pl. Aul. 4.10](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0032%3Aact%3D4%3Ascene%3D10).25
- With imperatives and future, *then*: “ergo, si sapis, mussitabis,” [Pl. Mil. 2.5](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0041%3Aact%3D2%3Ascene%3D5).66.

More explicitly, in modern scientific literature, Newton uses *ergo* (e.g. in his famous Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica, [sect. I](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Philosophiae_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica_-_SECT._I._DE_Methodo_rationum_primarum_%26_ultima_rum.).)

Anyway, Newton himself i) builds many conditional clauses starting with *si* and using a comma as the only link to the consequent, and ii) uses *ergo* alone to introduce stand-alone sentences as consequence of the reasoning in the previous ones.

#### Option 3: dein and other phrasal forms

Newton also uses **dein** (see [L&S entry for dein](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddein)) in the same context, and apparently more smoothly.

It is also worth mentioning what Tom and Hugh noted: *deinde* (long for *dein*) and additional phrases like **necesse est**. In fact, I also found Newton using **dico quod** as the link in the *Principia* ([Sect. III](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Philosophiae_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica_-_SECT._III._De_motu_corporum_in_Conicis_sectionibus_eccentri_cis.). Prop. XIV. Theor. VI.)

Comment: I'm still not sure whether it does the trick, it seems that may also be used to introduce a consequent in a separate sentence.

Comment: Newton's use of *dein* is the kind of thing I was after, and I accept this answer because of that. I consider *ergo* to be more "therefore", and *ex A sequitur, ut B* more "it follows from A that B". Although these are logically equivalent to "then" in some sense, they would not be used in the exact same way. I know I might be stubborn, but I look at it from the perspective of what I would like to express as a mathematician: "if A, then B". I did not expect the Romans to use modern style mathematical language, but it is interesting to see how close they got.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is worth mentioning in this context that a modern notation like

*p* ⇒ *q*

which we read in English either as *p implies q* or *if p **then** q,* can be read in Latin as *ex p, (sequitur) q* with an optional *sequitur,* along the lines of [*ex falso, (sequitur) quodlibet*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion). In most examples of *si p sequitur q,*  *p* is a proposition; when it is not, *ex* + Abl. can be used. It is a spatial metaphor, of course, but it works much better than its English counterparts *from* and *out of.*